# How are these 2 equations equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking at an example, which shows the following as part of the inductive step.

$ar^{k+1} = \frac{ar^{k+2} - ar^{k+1}}{r - 1}$

However I am struggling to see how the right hand side was derived from the left.

Can someone show me the steps for how they are equal please?

Comment: Factor $ar^{k+1}$ from the numerator on the RHS.

Comment: $ar^{k+2}-ar^{k+1}=ar^{k+1}r-ar^{k+1}=ar^{k+1}(r-1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \require{enclose} \dfrac{ar^{k+2} - ar^{k+1}}{r - 1}=\dfrac {ar^{k+1}\enclose {downdiagonalstrike}{(r-1)}}{\enclose{downdiagonalstrike}{r-1}}=ar^{k+1}$

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, you can multiply the left-hand-side by $(r-1) \over (r-1)$ like so:
$ar^{k+1} \cdot (r-1) \over (r-1)$. When you expand the numerator of the fraction, you use the distributive property. Take $ar^{k+1}$ and multiply it by each term in $(r-1)$. Consequently, the numerator becomes $ar^{k+2} - ar^{k+1}$ because of exponent laws and the denominator stays the same.

**Recall**: When multiplying two terms with exponents you must add the exponents together. This is why when you distribute, $ar^{k+1}$ becomes $ar^{k+2}$. You're adding the exponent of $r^1$ to the exponent of $ar^{k+1}$.